# Single layout for multiple screen without different layout folders in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a doubt. If i have one single xml file let's say res folder--> layout folder--> my.xml. i want to display this my.xml to all multiple screen size without creating layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi etc.., May i know what is the simple and best way to achieve this concept ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Place the file at res\layout\my.xml

Every single device will get that layout by default unless you create an alternative.

Comment: ok fine but if my device is 5'inch and that same apk was install in 10'inch Tab then the design feel and look is not good know?? what to do for that ??

Comment: That is why you have the ability to override your layouts with screen size specific ones but you stated you did not want to do that. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single layout file in the default location (res/layout/my.xml), then it will be used on all the devices that your app can be installed on.

However, that's usually not what you want because it will look very different on a device with a different size than what you developed on.  To handle this, you can start by creating another layout file in another directory (res/layout-sw600dp/my.xml).  This layout would be used for devices where the smallest width (sw) is 600dp, ie, tablets.